# Deleting Rows from MS SQL SERVER using radio button in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, html

I want to delete row/s in MS SQL using php but there's a problem with:

```
$ids = $_POST['id'];
```

[This is what happen when I click on a radio button and the "Delete" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5bMj.png)

```js
<?php
$serverName = "kwekwe-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"customerdb", "UID"=>"dbadmin", "PWD"=>"kwekwe" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
     $query = "SELECT * FROM Customer_Details";


 //execute the SQL query and return records
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)
         or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

 //Show results in table

 $o = '<table border=1 id="myTable">
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>&nbsp</th>
         <th>REC NUMBER</th>
         <th>CUSTOMER ID</th>
         <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
         <th>SEC-REGISTERED NAME</th>
         <th>TIN NUMBER</th>
         <th>STORE TYPE</th>
         <th>SIZE OF BUSINESS</th>
         <th>SELLER ID</th>
         <th>DATE OF ESTABLISHMENT</th>
         <th>TELEPHONE#/FAX</th>
         <th>PAYMENT TERMS</th>
         <th>SHIPPING INSTRUCTIONS</th>
         <th>NUMBER OF DOORS</th>
   <th>NUMBER OF WAREHOUSES</th>
   <th>OWNER</th>
   <th>PURCHASER/S</th>
   <th>ACCOUNTING HEAD</th>
   <th>WAREHOUSE HEAD</th>
   <th>OTHER PERSONNEL</th>
   <th>PAYMENT TERMS 2</th>
   <th>COLLECTION SCHEDULE</th>
   <th>DISCOUNT</th>
   <th>VOLUME</th>
   <th>MERCHANDISING</th>
   <th>VEHICLE</th>
   <th>DISTRIBUTION</th>
   <th>CSL</th>
   <th>ASSORTMENT</th>
   <th>PRICING</th>
   <th>MARGIN</th>
   <th>PRICE</th>
   <th>PROMOTION</th>
   <th>PEOPLE</th>
   <th>OTHERS</th>
   <th>REPLENISHMENT ORDERS</th>
   <th>ASSORTMENT/MERCHANDISING</th>
   <th>NEW PRODUCTS</th>
   <th>PRICING/PROMOTION</th>
   <th>PICTURE</th>
         </tr>
         </thead><tbody>';

      while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
          {
              $o .= '<tr><td><input type=radio name=id value='.$record ['Rec_No'].'></td>';
              $o .= '<td>'.$record ['Rec_No'].'</td>';
              $o .= '<td>'.$record ['Cust_ID'].'</td>';
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Cust_Name'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['SEC_Name'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['TIN Number'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Store_Type'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Size of Business'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Seller_ID'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.date('F d, Y',strtotime($record ['Date of Establishment'])).'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Telephone/Fax'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Payment Terms'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Shipping Instructions'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Number of Doors'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Number of Warehouses'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Owner'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Purchaser(s)'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Accounting Head'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Warehouse Head'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Other Personnel'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Payment Terms 2'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Collection Schedule'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Discount'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Volume'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Merchandising'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Marketing Vehicle'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Distribution'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['CSL'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Assortment'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Pricing'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Margin'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Price'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Promotion'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['People'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Others'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Replenishment Orders'].'</td>';  
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Assortment/Merchandising'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['New Products'].'</td>'; 
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Pricing/Promotions'].'</td>'; 
   $o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src="data:image/png;base64,' . $record['image'] . '"></td>';
     $o .='</tr>';
          }               

       $o .= '</tbody></table>';

       echo $o;
    //free result set memory
        //mssql_free_result($result);

    //close the connection
        //sqlsrv_close($dbhandle);
?>
 <form action="delete.php" method="POST">
 <br><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit">
 </form>
<?php
 $ids = $_POST['id'];
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $serverName = "MELODY-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"customerdb", "UID"=>"dbadmin", "PWD"=>"melodyjerah" );
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
 if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 $sql = "DELETE FROM Customer_Details WHERE Rec_Num =".$ids;
 sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
 echo "Row with ID ".$ids." has been deleted!";
 }
?>
```

Comment: i think you're receiving an error of undefined index because you're getting the value of id in Post array on initial load.. add isset to it or use this

`$ids = isset($_POST["id"]) ? $_POST["id"] : false;`

Comment: field name are different in delete query and select query "Rec_No" and "Rec_Num"

Comment: `delete.php?id=0+or+1=1` would be bad.  Use a paramaterized query.

Comment: @Semi-Friends the error is gone but it won't delete...

Comment: @AmitVisodiya even if i changed it still gives me an undefined index

Comment: echo your $sql and find out what the statement is when it is getting created right before your sqlsrv_query() function. If the SQL statement isn't valid, then there's your problem.

Comment: @kwekwe - Amit Visodiya is correct.. sorry for being lazy of not reading your entire code.. you should replace you SQL to
`"DELETE FROM Customer_Details WHERE Rec_No =".$ids;`

Comment: @Semi-Friends the code from Amit is working. when I replaced my sql code with your code, it wasnt able to delete the data

Comment: my answer is the same to his. its just that i provided the sql of which you're suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete multiple rows at once or single row ?
if u want to delete multiple rows then use check boxes instead of radio buttons 
else use hyperlink to delete a single row

like this

```
$o .= '<tr><td><a href="delete.php?id='.$record["Rec_No"].'">Delete</a></td>';
```

to delete multiple rows

```
$o .= '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value='.$record ['Rec_No'].'></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$serverName = "kwekwe-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "customerdb", "UID" => "dbadmin", "PWD" => "kwekwe");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM Customer_Details";


//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)
        or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

//Show results in table

$o = '<table border=1 id="myTable">
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>&nbsp</th>
         <th>REC NUMBER</th>
         <th>CUSTOMER ID</th>
         <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
         <th>SEC-REGISTERED NAME</th>
         <th>TIN NUMBER</th>
         <th>STORE TYPE</th>
         <th>SIZE OF BUSINESS</th>
         <th>SELLER ID</th>
         <th>DATE OF ESTABLISHMENT</th>
         <th>TELEPHONE#/FAX</th>
         <th>PAYMENT TERMS</th>
         <th>SHIPPING INSTRUCTIONS</th>
         <th>NUMBER OF DOORS</th>
         <th>NUMBER OF WAREHOUSES</th>
         <th>OWNER</th>
         <th>PURCHASER/S</th>
         <th>ACCOUNTING HEAD</th>
         <th>WAREHOUSE HEAD</th>
         <th>OTHER PERSONNEL</th>
         <th>PAYMENT TERMS 2</th>
         <th>COLLECTION SCHEDULE</th>
         <th>DISCOUNT</th>
         <th>VOLUME</th>
         <th>MERCHANDISING</th>
         <th>VEHICLE</th>
         <th>DISTRIBUTION</th>
         <th>CSL</th>
         <th>ASSORTMENT</th>
         <th>PRICING</th>
         <th>MARGIN</th>
         <th>PRICE</th>
         <th>PROMOTION</th>
         <th>PEOPLE</th>
         <th>OTHERS</th>
         <th>REPLENISHMENT ORDERS</th>
         <th>ASSORTMENT/MERCHANDISING</th>
         <th>NEW PRODUCTS</th>
         <th>PRICING/PROMOTION</th>
         <th>PICTURE</th>
         </tr>
         </thead><tbody>';

while ($record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    $o .= '<tr><td><input type=radio name=id value=' . $record ['Rec_No'] . '></td>';
    $o .= '<td>' . $record ['Rec_No'] . '</td>';
    $o .= '<td>' . $record ['Cust_ID'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Cust_Name'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['SEC_Name'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['TIN Number'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Store_Type'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Size of Business'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Seller_ID'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . date('F d, Y', strtotime($record ['Date of Establishment'])) . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Telephone/Fax'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Payment Terms'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Shipping Instructions'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Number of Doors'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Number of Warehouses'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Owner'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Purchaser(s)'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Accounting Head'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Warehouse Head'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Other Personnel'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Payment Terms 2'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Collection Schedule'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Discount'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Volume'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Merchandising'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Marketing Vehicle'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Distribution'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['CSL'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Assortment'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Pricing'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Margin'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Price'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Promotion'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['People'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Others'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Replenishment Orders'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Assortment/Merchandising'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['New Products'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td>' . $record ['Pricing/Promotions'] . '</td>';
    $o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src="data:image/png;base64,' . $record['image'] . '"></td>';
    $o .='</tr>';
}

$o .= '</tbody></table>';
?>
<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
    <?php echo $o; ?>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $serverName = "MELODY-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "customerdb", "UID" => "dbadmin", "PWD" => "melodyjerah");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Customer_Details WHERE Rec_No =" . $_POST['id'];
    sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    echo "Row with ID " . $_POST['id'] . " has been deleted!";
    }else{
        echo "ID is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Amit ! it works. but there's an error here: [echo "Row with ID " . $ids . " has been deleted!";]

Comment: I already troubleshooted it. it lacks [$ids = $_POST['id'];]
at the top of echo.

Comment: @kwekwe Yes, see my updated answer. and accept answer if it helpfull to you.